# static initialisation order issue with static/dynamic linking

Tags: c++, c++11

If a c++ application is organised in following manner

```
//file1.cpp
static Y sgObj = X::getInitObject(0);  //declared in file scope

//file2.cpp
namespace{
   int getInitValue()
   {
      static int val = Y::sObj.initVal();
      return val;
   }
}

namespace X{
   Y getInitObject(int initVal)
   {
      if(initVal < getInitValue())
      {
         cout << "Print some log message" << endl;
      } 

      return Y::initMethod(initVal);
   }
}

//file.h
//This class is shipped as static and dynamic library, and application is supposed to link 
//them in their executable based on their need
class Y{
public:
int initVal();
static Y initMethod(int val);
static Y sObj;
};
```

Assuming all the necessary header files are included and we are able to create the executable for this application, does it have initialization issue with the way I am creating the object in file1.cpp when:

- statically 
    vs
- dynamically linking with the library(corresponding to implementation of class Y) for creating the object sgObj.

Given the class Y's implementation is not exposed to application, we can't change the way its static member sObj is created.

Does it have anything to do with platform / compiler being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either assure that `file1.cpp` includes `<iostream>` before the definition of `sgObj` or you need to construct a local object of type `std::ios_base::Init` before you use `cout` during the static initialization:

```
  if(initVal < getInitValue())
  {
     (void)std::ios_base::Init{};
     cout << "Print some log message" << endl;
  }
```

Otherwise `cout` might not be initialized when you reach that line.

---

Other than that, the order in which `Y::sObj` and the global `sgObj` are constructed is indeterminate, assuming `Y::sObj` is defined in another translation unit not shown, because the order in which dynamic initialization between different translation units happens is indeterminate.

Therefore, if `Y::initMethod`, which is called from the global initialization of `sgObj` accesses `Y::sObj` it might not be initialized yet, causing undefined behavior.

If you want to be able to use the static `Y::sObj` during static initialization of other non-local static variables, you need to use something like the Meyers singleton pattern:

```
class Y{
//...
    static Y& sObj {
        static Y instance /* initializer here */;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

To be used as `Y::sObj()` instead of `Y::sObj`.

Comment: given that application doesn't have access to the class Y implementation is there any other way we can get around this indeterminate object creation issue? Will it have issue in both the cases, i.e. linking statically of dynamically?

Comment: @DineshMaurya You can use the Meyers singleton also for the global `sgObj` instead. You just need to make sure that not both of them have non-local static storage duration. It doesn't matter whether you link statically or dynamically. (There might be some specific other guarantees on certain platforms and/or compiler extensions that allow you to specify the construction order across compilation units, but nothing portable.)